# How to create a nested dictionary to post data?

Tags: go

```
{
    "data": {
        "payload": {
            "from": {
                "phone_number": "+XXXXXXXXXX"
            },

            "to": {
                "phone_number": "+XXXXXXXXXX",
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a nested dictionary for the post body. I've tried using struct but it didn't work as I expected and while using the map[string]interface{}{} I'm getting an error.

1. Struct Route:

```
type Payload struct {
    From struct {
        PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`
    }
    To  struct {
        PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`
    }
}


type Response struct {
    Data struct {
        Payload Payload `json:"payload"`
    }
}


func main() {
  // extra code

  payload := Payload{
        From: struct {PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`}(struct{ PhoneNumber string }{PhoneNumber: sender}),
        To: struct {PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`}(struct{ PhoneNumber string }{PhoneNumber: recipient})}
    response := Response{Data: struct {
        Payload Payload `json:"payload"`
    }(struct{ Payload Payload }{Payload: payload})}
  fmt.Println(response)
}
```

The above response is:

```
{{{{+XXXXXXXXXX} {+XXXXXXXXXX}}}}
```

2. Raw dict creation:

```
var payload = map[string]interface{}{}
payload["from"].(map[string]string)["phone_number"] = sender
payload["to"].(map[string]string)["phone_number"] = recipient
fmt.Println(payload)

var response = map[string]interface{}{}
response["data"].(map[string]string)["payload"] = payload
```

Error: Cannot use 'payload' (type map[string]interface{}) as the type string

I would highly appreciate it if you could guide me in the correct direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the Convert [JSON to Go struct](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/), that generate a struct like:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Data Data `json:"data"`
}
type From struct {
    PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`
}
type To struct {
    PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`
}
type Payload struct {
    From From `json:"from"`
    To   To   `json:"to"`
}
type Data struct {
    Payload Payload `json:"payload"`
}
```

and use, as example:

```
outStruct := AutoGenerated{
    Data: Data{
        Payload: Payload{
            From: From{PhoneNumber: sender},
            To:   To{PhoneNumber: recipient},
        },
    },
}
out, err := json.Marshal(outStruct)
fmt.Println(string(out), err)
```

this will out

```
{"data":{"payload":{"from":{"phone_number":"234234"},"to":{"phone_number":"32434"}}}} <nil>
```

Comment: Am I creating the response object correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of your code. When you were trying to create a raw map I think you were assigning value to nil map that's why you were getting error.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type (
    Response struct {
        Data Data `json:"data"`
    }

    Data struct {
        PayLoad PayLoad `json:"payload"`
    }

    PayLoad struct {
        From Address `json:"from"`
        To   Address `json:"to"`
    }

    Address struct {
        PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`
    }
)

func main() {
    payload := PayLoad{
        From: Address{PhoneNumber: "+1xxxxxxxxx"},
        To:   Address{PhoneNumber: "+1xxxxxxxxx"},
    }

    resp := Response{
        Data: Data{
            PayLoad: payload,
        },
    }

    j, _ := json.Marshal(resp)
    fmt.Println(string(j))

    // with map

    var payloadNew = map[string]interface{}{
        "from": map[string]interface{}{
            "phone_number": "+1xxxxxxxx",
        },
        "to": map[string]interface{}{
            "phone_number": "+1yyyyyyyy",
        },
    }

    var responseNew = map[string]interface{}{
        "data": map[string]interface{}{
            "payload": payloadNew,
        },
    }

    j, _ = json.Marshal(responseNew)
    fmt.Println(string(j))
}
```

The json outputs are:

```json
{"data":{"payload":{"from":{"phone_number":"+1xxxxxxxxx"},"to":{"phone_number":"+1xxxxxxxxx"}}}}
{"data":{"payload":{"from":{"phone_number":"+1xxxxxxxx"},"to":{"phone_number":"+1yyyyyyyy"}}}}
```